# Is it possible to disconnect using the bittorrent protocol?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, bittorrent

Currently, A and B are transferring files 1:1. I'm trying to run code that disconnects the torrent from B.

Using the codes introduced at https://www.npmjs.com/package/bittorrent-protocol
I tried to disconnect the current connection using

```
wire.choke()
wire.uninterested()
```

However, the file is still being transferred.
I wonder why it doesn't work as intended.

Comment: What do you mean with "it doesn't work as intended"? Please add explaination to your question with [edit]

Answer (score 2):

There is no explicit shutdown signalling on the bittorrent layer. To disconnect a bittorrent peer you have to close the underlying TCP connection.